# How do i hang shelving on drywall over concrete

Tags: drywall

i do know that there is concrete behind the drywall because it is a fire wall. I cannot drill into it for obvious reasons not to mention, the owner wont allow it. Any ides? thanks. Lewis

Answer (score 0):

I would get some prefinished 1 x 4's and glue them with construction adhesive (liquid nails) to the drywall vertically to provide a solid surface to fasten the shelving to. Place one every 16 to 24 inches and you will be fine.